# Query to pull the person records for age range is between age >= 5 and age <8 in calendar year 2019

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write an Oracle SQL query to pull all the person records with an age range greater than or equal to 5 and less than or equal to 8 in calendar year 2019.

Even the person reaches age greater than or equal to 5 any part of the year I need to pull into base population. A person could be 8 on 01/01/2019 and turn 9 on 02/01/2019 and I need to include him in my base population.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

- The oldest someone could be is 8 on `2019-01-01` and then 9 on `2019-01-02` which would mean they were born after `2010-01-01`; and
- The youngest is age 5 on `2019-12-31` which would mean they were born on `2014-12-31` (or before `2015-01-01`).

Assuming that you have a `date_of_birth` column with the `DATE` data type then all you need to do is query that range:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  date_of_birth > DATE '2010-01-01'
AND    date_of_birth < DATE '2015-01-01';
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! The oldest record that I consider is who has the age = 8 any part of the year in 2019?  Would this work?

Comment: @red It is basic date arithmetic, yes, it will work. I've updated the answer from maximum of 9 to maximum of 8 but all that does is shift the lower bound of the range by 1 year (unsurprisingly since the age has changed by a year).